# Error directing Bootstrap pagination's navigation links using GET method

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am using GET method to display pagination for a page(home.php) that displays the results of a search done on a form(index.php). The problem is that I don't know how to direct to the next page. What I am currently doing does not direct at all.

```
index.php

<form action='home.php' action='get'>
//Form elements
</form>

home.php

if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

//Display search results

//Shows pagination
$page_count2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offers WHERE school = :school"; 
$rs_result =  $db-> query($page_count2, array('school' => $_GET['school'])); 
$row = $rs_result->fetch(); 
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 6); 

echo "
<div class='row text-center'>
<ul class='pagination  pag'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

    if ($page == $i)
           echo "<li class='active' >";
    else
           echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href='$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?page=$i' >$i</a></li>"; //This is my problem
};
echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'Typo Error

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: It is not directing. It remains on the same page but the url on the address bar changes. On the URL bar for page 2, I see something like this: "http://5.10.68.188/~offcamp1/home.php?school=Ahmadu+Bello+University+Zaria&accommodation=see+all&price=see+all&submit=Search?page=2?page=2"